# Word, Make Style Match "Based On" Style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, styles

I am trying to build a proper Table of contents in Word and would like to show 5 levels. I have a problem in that my TOC 5 has a bunch of customizations in it, and no matter what I do I can not get it to match the TOC 2 style I have it "based on." Is there a way to reset the style customizations so it'll actually match the based on style identically?

I need to adjust the hanging indent so I can not just used TOC 2 when creating the table, and I've had this issue with other styles in the past.

As can be seen in the figures below, TOC 4 just says "based on TOC 2," while TOC 5 has customizations.

[image: Style Window]
[image: Style Window 2]

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Based On" for an existing style, it does not change the style's formatting but rather shows you the different formatting in the Modify Style dialog.

### Method 1: Use the Modify Style dialog for your TOC 5 style

1. Take a look at the settings in your TOC 2 style. You can use the Reveal Formatting Pane (`Shift`+`F1`) for this. You may want to take a screenshot of that pane. Here is my writing on [Showing Formatting](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#RevealCodes).
2. Then, in the Modify Style dialog for TOC 5, change the settings to be the same using the Format drop-down.

### Method 2: Change the formatting of any TOC 5 paragraph to match TOC 2

Again, get the settings of a TOC 2 paragraph and change the TOC 5 paragraph to match. It should automatically update.

**Here are some resources:**

- [Managing Word Styles](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- My chapter on [Understanding Word Styles](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm)